# Why doesn't Linux support mmap by path?

Tags: linux-kernel

The `mmap` syscall needs a fd as parameter, but when you close that fd, the mmap is still alive in the process's memory address space.

Therefore keeping an mmap doesn't need an opened fd, so why dose Linux  only support creating an mmap of a file using a fd, but not a file-name-path? Wouldn't it be nice if we can have a `mmapat` syscall just like `openat` and `execveat`?

If `mmap` creates an extra reference to that file, why can't we have a `mmapat` which atomically creates such an reference at the first time without take an fd of the process then release it later.

Is there any historical or security reason for not having such syscall on Linux kernel?

Comment: The `*_at` differ from their non-at counterparts by being able to resolve relative path wrt to an open `fd` to a directory instead of the cwd, not by using a path instead of a file descriptor. As to why your `mmap_path()` is not implemented in the kernel, the keyword from your question is **"atomically"**. Good luck doing it atomically.

Comment: @mosvy But `mmap` never support path. While other functions support path either *at or non-at version.

Comment: That's why I was suggesting you to rename it `mmap_path()` ;-)

Answer (score 5):

mmap(2) is basically a read(2) to a buffer that the kernel is going to write to directly, rather than reading to a kernel buffer and then copying to the provided buffer.

There's no mmapat(2) for the same reason there's no readat(2).

The file descriptor isn't needed any more because

> The mmap() function adds an extra reference to the file associated with the file descriptor fildes which is not removed by a subsequent close() on that file descriptor. This reference is removed when there are no more mappings to the file.

This is per [the OpenGroup's website.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html)  They're the people who mange the POSIX standard, if I'm not mistaken, so they should know.

Comment: You can't write to a mmaped file after all fd of it are closed even though the mmap is PROT_WRITE|MAP_SHARED ?

Comment: I didn't say whether or not you can write to an mmapped file after the fd is closed. I said if you can write to the file through the closed fd then it's magic.

Comment: And just found the reference I was looking for, and yeah, it's magic. Specifically, implicit dup(2) magic. I should learn to date-check references before accepting them. Google returned two links, and I guessed the first would be the better link because Google. Sigh.

Comment: Yeah, but if it creates an extra reference, why can't we have mmapat which create such extra reference at the first time?

Comment: mmap is basically an alternate implementation of read.  You can if you want write the wrapper function you're asking for and use it yourself, but you'll have about as much luck getting a standard library to incorporate it as you would having them incorporate readat.